# Comment choisir entre deux bonnes réponses ?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Bonjour,

(english impossible for me sorry)

Sur ma question [je puis je peux dans une poésie de Victor Hugo](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/je-puis-je-peux-et-la-poesie), je suis très géné de dire *Telle réponse est LA solution*. Je trouve que les deux qui m'ont été faites pour l'instant sont excellentes. À la limite, j'ai l'impression que ma question ne convient pas forcément au format stackexchange, c'est un peu de ma faute.

Comment faire alors pour dire *merci* à tous les deux ? Il existe un mode wiki, je crois, qui correspondrait mieux peut être à ce genre de truc, mais j'ai peur que ça bouffe les points des gens.

Comment voyez-vous les choses ?

Answer (score 4):

La question me semble dans les limites du format StackExchange. Il est vrai que les questions subjectives sont de manière générale déconseillées, mais quand on parle de langage, le subjectif n'est jamais très loin… Donc, je garderai la question telle quelle. Pas de mode « wiki communautaire » non plus, son utilisation (un peu controversée) est rare, et ne convient pas ici.

Pour dire *merci* aux deux réponses, il suffit de voter pour les deux. Après, il n'est pas possible d'accepter les deux, et je te conseille d'accepter celle qui te « parle » le plus… Les commentaires mis sous chaque réponse sont très bien, et montrent bien que les deux te semblent satisfaisantes.